# cocoa: how to implement a addressBook

Tags: cocoa

I'm wondering how to implement an addressBook person info view. like
[image]

if a person has different tag, the view will display differently.
[image]

is there an easy way to implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to build that view. There's a built-in [ABPeoplePickerView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABPeoplePickerView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that provides that behaviour.